# Tetrahedrons and Octahedrons

Tags: geometry, dissection

Is it possible to cut a regular tetrahedron with edge length 100
into regular [tetrahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) with edges of length less than 1 
and  regular [octahedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron)  with edges of length less than 1?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. There's a [solid tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral-octahedral_honeycomb) of tetrahedra and octahedra that fills a tetraderon. Making a sufficiently large tetrahedron this way and scaling is down to the right size solves the problem.

[image]

One way to obtain the tiling is to cut to tetradhedron with slices parallel to each face that are spaced apart at even intervals of $1/200^{th}$ of its height.

Comment: Perfect answer to nice question and +1 for the picture. (But shouldn't the picture end at a point at the bottom, rather than an edge?)

Comment: @BmyGuest Yes, I couldn't find a picture that had the tiling in the shape of a tetrahedron, this was the closest I saw.

Comment: Here's a very bad photoshop I made using the above image showing it as a tetrahedron http://i.stack.imgur.com/CETMj.png